# Not unique table/alias codeigniter

Tags: mysql

I get the error ERROR 1066 (42000): Not unique table/alias: 'order_has_artikelgroup' I cant figure out whats wrong with it.

```
SELECT
      `artikel`.`foto_naam`,
      `fotografer`.`id`,
      `fotografer`.`name_fotografer`,
      `customer`.`first_name`,
      `customer`.`last_name`,
      `fotografer`.`domain_name`,
      `fotografer`.`email`,
      `order`.`invoice_no`,
      `order`.`order_cost`,
      `order`.`total_cost`,
      `order`.`invoice_date`,
      `order`.`payment`,
      `order`.`status`
    FROM
      `artikel_group`
      INNER JOIN `artikel` ON `artikel_group`.`id` = `artikel`.`artikelgroup_id`
      INNER JOIN `fotografer` ON `artikel_group`.`fotografer_id` = `fotografer`.`id`
      INNER JOIN `order_has_artikelgroup` ON `order_has_artikelgroup`.`order_id` = `order`.`id`
      INNER JOIN `order_has_artikelgroup` ON `order_has_artikelgroup`.`artikelgroup_id` = `artikel_group`.`id`
      INNER JOIN `customer` ON `order`.`customer_id` = `customer`.`id`
```

Answer (score 1):

you've got two times a join on table

> order_has_artikelgroup

```
INNER JOIN `order_has_artikelgroup` ON `order_has_artikelgroup`.`order_id` = `order`.`id`
INNER JOIN `order_has_artikelgroup` ON `order_has_artikelgroup`.`artikelgroup_id` = `artikel_group`.`id`
```

but every element queried must be unique.

So you should either add an alias

something like

```
INNER JOIN `order_has_artikelgroup` oha ON oha.`order_id` = `order`.`id`
INNER JOIN `order_has_artikelgroup` oha2 ON oha2 .`artikelgroup_id` = `artikel_group`.`id`
```

(and use oha and oha2 in your select clause also if you need them)

or change your join (depending on the logic of the query)

```
INNER JOIN `order_has_artikelgroup` 
   ON `order_has_artikelgroup`.`order_id` = `order`.`id` and
      `order_has_artikel_group`.`artikelgroup_id` = `artikel_group`.`id`
```